How to send audio in telegram bot?
I am trying to create a telegram bot and I am using an API that download videos as mp3, so when the user send a video URL I send him mp3 file of it that he can stream or download, although everything is working fine but the bot always returns:

"Sorry, I couldn't convert the video. Please try again with a valid YouTube URL"

This is the code I am using:
async def convert_to_mp3(update, context):
    # Get the message text
    message_text = update.message.text
    
    # Check if the message contains a YouTube URL
    if 'youtube.com' in message_text or 'youtu.be' in message_text:
        # API endpoint and headers
        url = "https://youtube-mp315.p.rapidapi.com/"
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "rapidAPI-Key",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "youtube-mp315.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
        
        # Query parameters
        querystring = {"url": message_text}

        # Making the API call
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        data = response.json()
        print("API Response:", data)  # Debugging


        # Check if the response contains the MP3 URL
        if 'url' in data:
            await update.message.reply_audio(data['url'])
        else:
            await update.message.reply_text("Sorry, I couldn't convert the video. Please try again with a valid YouTube URL.")
    else:
        await update.message.reply_text("Please send a valid YouTube video URL.")


1- Change update.message.reply_audio(data['url']) to update.message.reply_audio(data['result'][0]['url']) to send the URL as a sample JSON response is like this:
{
'result':
    [
        {
        'status': 'true',
        'title': "Doston Ergashev - Ko'zmunchog'im | Достон Эргашев - Кузмунчогим",
        'channel': 'RizaNovaUZ',
        'duration': '5:47',
        'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WVl6g5hvcDA/hqdefault.jpg',
        'url': 'https://dl01.yt-dl.click/api/stream?t=vmJiaO1pJVwMQXdV2F6cW&e=1715256371785&h=0M0zBAtRD1Xqy-9kqWQvgq7gbWCiteYI3D_75S9ZwaE&s=HDMRIY6WQQS-QeLknpN2bfIahvqOOYA9sbfVd9D_Rus&i=zlJRum6WIGJrebZNOm_Zng'
        }
    ]
}

2- If the video is not found the code will output "None" so change your if statement to this:
if url != "None":
    await update.message.reply_audio(data['result'][0]['url'])
else:
    await update.message.reply_text("Sorry, I couldn't convert the video. Please try again with a valid YouTube URL.")

